# Full Text Search FTSFacade Unauthorized issue EPiServer 6 R2

Tags: episerver

I'm using Windows Authentication in IIS and whenever I try to run Full Text Search index job from adminmode the errorlog gives me this and the Full Text Search service cannot build the index (Main and Ref folders):

```
2013-04-29 11:09:00,898 [65] EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.GetNamedIndexes(:0) - Could not get named indexes for uri 'http://epi.hfabintranetv2/IndexingService/IndexingService.svc/namedindexes/?accesskey=E8308A19-5FC4-484C-8E85-C9987884CD07'. Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.MakeHttpRequest(String url, NamedIndexingServiceElement namedIndexingServiceElement, String method, Stream postData, Action`1 responseHandler)
at EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.GetNamedIndexes(String namedIndexingService)
2013-04-29 11:09:24,462 [64] EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.SendRequest(:0) - Update batch could not be sent to service uri 'http://epi.hfabintranetv2/IndexingService/IndexingService.svc/update/?accesskey=E8308A19-5FC4-484C-8E85-C9987884CD07'. Message: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.MakeHttpRequest(String url, NamedIndexingServiceElement namedIndexingServiceElement, String method, Stream postData, Action`1 responseHandler)
at EPiServer.Search.RequestHandler.SendRequest(SyndicationFeed feed, String namedIndexingService, Collection`1 ids)'
```

I've noticed that setting Anonymous Authentication to Enabled in IIS lets Full Text Search service create the index (Main and Ref folders).Any clues on why it is not rebuilding the index while using Windows Authentication?

Comment: Does the service account have the proper permissions?

Comment: Which service account? Where can I find it?

Comment: Actually I get the same error when I run the public JsonResult ReIndex() method in ReIndexController.cs using the dashboard gadget. So this doesn't seem to be related to the ScheduledPlugin Index Job that I have in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to set Windows Authentication on the root folder of your site and then settings the IndexingService folder where the .svc file is, to Anonymous Authentication.